# How to use route.params in Vue to fill inputs with data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I'm working on a to-do-app using Vue. I use Task component to create new Task, but I also want to use this component to edit existing tasks. It recieves tasks's id via link-router ($route.params.id), then i use computed property called task to get the specific task from the store, but I have no ide how to add data to data property now. Code below. Any help? Repo is here: https://github.com/Bartosz94094/vue-to-do-app.

```
<template>
  <section class="task">
    {{ $route.params.id }}
    <header><h2 class="task__header">Task</h2></header>
    <div class="task__title-field">
      <label for="title">Title (required)</label>
      <input
        class="task__title-input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Title"
        id="title"
        v-model="title"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="task__description-field">
      <label for="description">Description (optional)</label>
      <textarea
        class="task__description-input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Title"
        id="description"
        v-model="description"
        rows="10"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="task__date-field">
      <label for="date">Creation date (required)</label>
      <input
        class="task__date-input"
        type="datetime-local"
        id="date"
        v-model="created"
      />
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="task__status-field">
      <label for="status">Complited</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="status" v-model="status" />
    </div> -->
    <button
      class="task__save-btn"
      :disabled="$v.$invalid"
      @click.prevent="save"
    >
      Save
    </button>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { validationMixin } from "vuelidate";
import { required } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
  name: "Task",
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      created: "",
      status: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      this.$store.commit("addNewTask", {
        title: this.title,
        description: this.description,
        created: this.created,
        status: this.status,
      });
    },
  },
  computed: {
    task() {
      return this.$store.getters.task(Number(this.$route.params.id));
    },
  },
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  validations: {
    title: {
      required,
    },
    created: {
      required,
    },
    status: {
      required,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Add what data to which data property?

Answer (score 1):

When getting the data using the getter, first define a variable and store the data in that variable and then use watch property to set the component level data property.

```
task () {
  return this.$store.getters.task(Number(this.$route.params.id));
}

watch: {
  task: {
    deep: true,
    handler: function(newVal) {
      this.title = newVal.title,
      this.description = newVal.description,
      this.created = newVal.created,
      this.status = newVal.status
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "unexpected side effect in computed property"